# Infinity Norm Bound

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f:[0,L]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ is smooth and $L>1$. Does there exist a bound
$$\|f\|_{\infty}\le c\|f\|_{1}$$ where $c=c(f,L)$ may depend on $f$ and $L$? I am having a difficult time proving or disproving.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If you want $c$ to depend upon $f$ as well, of course you can trivially take $c(f, L)=2\frac{||f||_{\infty}}{||f||_1}.$ Any such bound, I doubt, will be meaningless. The correct thing to ask would be $c=c(L).$
And, in that case, there can not be such a bound. Let $L=2,$ and take $f_n(x)=(\frac{x}{2})^n.$ It is clear that $||f_n||_{\infty}=1.$ But $||f_n||_{1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)2^n}\to 0.$

Comment: For my purpose, $c=c(f,L)$ suffices.  Is it possible for $c$ to be proportional to a product of norms of $f$, as opposed to a ratio?

Comment: I am not sure, but I feel that it is not possible. Suppose you find such a $c(f, L)$. Since $||f||_1\le L||f||_{\infty},$ it would force that $\frac{1}{L}\le c(f,L).$ Now, if we fix $L$, then it would mean something like $c(f)\ge 1$ for all $f.$ I doubt any reasonable $c$ will do so. In particular, for example if you want to look at the product of the norms of $f$, then that would not work because we can always play around the norms so that we can fix the $||f||_{\infty}$ norm and let $||f||_1$ go to zero.